# Getting Theme Function to Sort Posts Based on View Count Instead of Date

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, jss

I'm trying to edit this theme to sort displayed posts based on View Counts instead of Default Date. I've found the function I'm just not sure how approach this.

It's currently set as $orderby = 'rand' and displays posts in random order. Anything more I can do to this to sort by view counts? Such as replace 'rand' with view_count_variable?

```
  if ( ! function_exists( 'penci_custom_posts_oderby' ) ) {
          function penci_custom_posts_oderby( $query ) {
              if ( ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || ( 
      $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) ) {
                  $orderby = get_theme_mod( 
      'penci_general_post_oderby' );
                  if( !$orderby ): $orderby = 'rand'; endif;
                  $order = get_theme_mod( 'penci_general_post_order' 
      );
                  if( !$order ): $order = 'DESC'; endif;

                   if( ! function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) || ( 
      function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && ! is_woocommerce() ) ) {
                      $query->set( 'orderby', $orderby );
                      $query->set( 'order', $order );
                  }
              }
          }

          add_action('pre_get_posts','penci_custom_posts_oderby');
      }
```

Is this possible using a post meta key or? I do have a function called penci_get_post_views( $post->ID ) that returns post view counts for all separate posts, just not sure how to use it within this context. 
Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. but I haven't tested it out, so tell me whats the result.

```
      if ( ! function_exists( 'penci_custom_posts_oderby' ) ) {
          function penci_custom_posts_oderby( $query ) {
              if ( ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || ( 
      $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) ) {
                  $orderby = get_theme_mod( 
      'penci_general_post_oderby' );
                  if( !$orderby ):
                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'post_views_count' );
                    $orderby = [ 
                      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                      'order' => 'DESC',
                    ];
                  endif;
                  $order = get_theme_mod( 'penci_general_post_order');
                  if( !$order ): $order = 'DESC'; endif;

                   if( ! function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) || ( 
      function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && ! is_woocommerce() ) ) {
                      $query->set( 'orderby', $orderby );
                      $query->set( 'order', $order );
                  }
              }
          }

          add_action('pre_get_posts','penci_custom_posts_oderby');
      }
```